# SearchView displaying wrong ListView items

Tags: java, android, listview, searchview, custom-adapter

I am having trouble with the SearchView in my app displaying incorrect ListView items.

**If I type Name:** ListView is displayed as expected

**If I type Name1:** I get entries 1-2

**If I type Name 2-11:** I get the entry for Name1

---

**Here is a visual:**
[image: Visual]

---

As far as I cant tell, the code is fine but the application is not working as expected. Could somebody please point me in the right direction to fixing this?

---

The ListView is displayed with a custom array adapter from the following data:

```
[{"society_id":1,"name":"Name1","email":"Test@email1","description":"TestDes1"},
{"society_id":2,"name":"Name2","email":"Test@email2","description":"TestDes2"},
{"society_id":3,"name":"Name3","email":"Test@email3","description":"TestDes3"},...]
```

**SocietySearch.java:**

```
public class SocietySearch extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { //TODO remember notifyDataSetChanged
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_society_search);

        List<Society> societies = new ArrayList<>();
        ServerRequests serverRequest1 = new ServerRequests(SocietySearch.this);
        serverRequest1.GetSocietyDataAsyncTask(societies, new GetSocietyCallback() {

            @Override
            public void done(final List<Society> societies) {
                ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
                List<ListViewItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
                for (final Society s : societies) {
                    items.add(new ListViewItem() {{
                        ThumbnailResource = R.drawable.test;
                        Title = s.socName;
                        Description = s.socDes;
                    }});
                }
                final CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(SocietySearch.this, items, societies);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
                SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);
                searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
                searchView.setQueryHint("Search..");

                searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                        adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    public class ListViewItem {
        public int ThumbnailResource;
        public String Title;
        public String Description;
    }
```

**CustomListViewAdapter.java:**

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<SocietySearch.ListViewItem> items;

    public CustomListViewAdapter(Activity context, List<SocietySearch.ListViewItem> items, List<Society> societies) {

        super(context, R.layout.item_row, societies);

        this.items = items;
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Auto-generated method stub

        ListViewItem item = items.get(position);

        View vi = convertView;

        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, null);

        ImageView test = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imgThumbnail);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        TextView txtSubTitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtSubTitle);

        test.setImageResource(item.ThumbnailResource);
        txtTitle.setText(item.Title);
        txtSubTitle.setText(item.Description);


        return vi;
    }
}
```

**Society.java:**

```
public class Society {

    String socName, socEmail, socDes;
    int society_id;

    public Society(int society_id, String socName, String socEmail, String socDes) {

        this.society_id = society_id;
        this.socName = socName;
        this.socEmail = socEmail;
        this.socDes = socDes;

    }

    public String toString() {
        return socName;
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="k.unionapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeScreenActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".SocietySearch"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide implementation of `toString` method in `SocietySearch.ListViewItem` class, which will return name of item.

```
public class ListViewItem {
    public int ThumbnailResource;
    public String Title;
    public String Description;

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return Title;
    }
}
```

Default implementation of filter in `ArrayAdapter` uses this method to convert arbitrary item type into `String` before comparing it to search query. Also, default implementation - `ArrayFilter` - uses query string as prefix, FYI.

---

Also, as noted in other answer - don't hold onto original list in your constructor and `getView` method. Use `getItem` method of array adapter itself.

You also might want to change class declaration to include custom type of items instead of generic `Object`:

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SocietySearch.ListViewItem> {
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same results for this

Comment: Trying it all out, extending with  ArrayAdapter<SocietySearch.ListViewItem> provides errors for my super()

Comment: Line `super(context, R.layout.item_row, societies);`, replace `societies` with `items`. Why do you have arguments in constructor which you don't use?

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This works nicely, you've really helped me out. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you problem may be because you are holding onto the original list in memory, and binding your view off of that

```
ListViewItem item = items.get(position);
```

Instead, you may want to try getting the item from the adapter itself, since the underlying list is being changed by the `Filter`

```
ListViewItem item = this.getItem(position);
```

Comment: there is no such method in ArrayAdapter, but there is `getItem(int position)`

Comment: Thanks. Copy-paste err, fixed